# Cron jobs not running while OS is locked

Tags: 15.04, cron, desktop-background

I have a cron job that runs a simple bash script to swap out the current wallpaper with a random image from my wallpapers folder every minute. This works fantastically for me. However, whenever I lock my screen, the cron job stops running.

Is it possible to make the cron job always run, even while locked?

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 1):

If your computer is sleeping rather than just locked, nothing will run, including cron jobs. To correct that, change whatever setting is causing your computer to sleep so that it only locks the screen.