# How to automate a cronjob task when my screen is locked

Tags: cron, lock-screen

I want to automate my cronjob to automate backups, but will I be able to automate backups when my screen is locked and how can I do it.

I read [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/636763/cron-jobs-not-running-while-os-is-locked) but I'm not sure how to go about it.

Thankyou

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. The screen is locked and the computer is sleeping are not the same thing. We can't solve problems that do not exist.

Comment: Here is a simple tutorial about how to setup a cron job. https://www.tecmint.com/create-and-manage-cron-jobs-on-linux/ Cron will run if the computer is powered on and the screen is locked but not if it’s sleeping. You might find it convenient to use anacron which will run jobs when the start time is missed due to the computer being off.